# Clicking submit button does nothing using jquery delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, firefox, delegates

I am trying to use a form in a website  which is loaded through javascript (from the results of an ajax call), the submit button calls a delegate function which sends an ajax call.

This works perfectly in Chrome and IE, but in firefox clicking the button does nothing, there are no javascript errors or anything either.

**14/04/2014 EDIT: This has just started happening in chrome as well, after no changes to the code**

The form is built:

```
tr += "<form  method='POST' data-opid='"+resultArr[i].columns.number+"'
      class='update_form' action='' name='form"+resultArr[i].columns.number+"'>";

tr += "<td><input type='submit' class='update' value='update'></td></form>";
```

And the delegate function starts:

```
jQuery(document).delegate(".update_form", "submit", function(e){
   alert("in the delegate");
```

But the alert never triggers in firefox.

I have a `<a class='displayopp' href='../partner_detail/view/" + resultArr[i].columns.internalid.internalid + "'>` that uses `jQuery(document).delegate(".displayopp", "click", function(e){` perfectly.

I have been looking to see if there are any firefox issues with delegate but have been unable to find anything. I have noticed another form loaded with javascript pressing "enter" to submit wont work, but other than that im not sure where to look.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I have attempted to minimise my code to only the relevant information, as the file is 500 lines long (for various reasons im not happy with), so let me know if i havent provided enough information.

As mentioned earlier the problem is only in firefox, everything else works fine.

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7 or higher, I would recommend using `.on()` instead (check the documentation on how to migrate), though I'm not sure if that will solve the issue. Most of the time when a delegated event handler isn't called, it's because the event doesn't bubble (though I think `submit` does), or another handler is calling `stopPropagation` before reaching the container (`document` in your case).

Comment: From memory, I first built this using `on()`, but because the form is created after the page is loaded it wouldnt find it (does this make sense? i may be thinking of another change, i only know for certainwe changed something for that reason, and we tried `on()` at one stage) The big problem is I built this late last year, and cant remember all migrations of the code.

Comment: There is a version of `.on()` that works that way, as long as you're using at least 1.7: `$('container').on('event', 'selector', function() {...})`. See [direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). But again, you can try that but I doubt it's the issue.

Comment: used `jQuery(document).on("submit", ".update_form", function(e){` and no change

Comment: Added not that As of about 4-5 hours ago, this issue has been occuring in Chrome as well, including "pressing "enter" to submit" in the other form. Exactly the same behaviour, no changes to this copy of the code for a number of weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, and it wasn't in the code i gave you sorry. 
the form was declared:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <form>
            <td>form input</td>
            <td>form input</td>
            <td>form submit</td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I changed this to be:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>form input</td>
            <td>form input</td>
            <td>form submit</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And everything works!

Once I knew what the problem was I found a [page](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/tables.html) that stated

> Tables and forms can be nested either way. But if you put forms into tables, each form must be completely included into a single table cell (one TD element in practice). Thereby the forms are each completely independent.

So it was an order issue, and IE and chrome originally work because they were awesome, I dont want to say that IE continued to work cos it was awesome, so I wont say it.